# How to create a transparent curved transparent rectangle at center of the screen?

Tags: java, android

How to create a transparent curved transparent rectangle at center of the screen?

I have written the following code and added alpha for the curved rectangle at center of the screen, but the background color is being shown instead of transparency

```
int width = canvas.getWidth();
int height = canvas.getHeight();
Rect childRect = this.getChildRect();

Paint outerPaint = new Paint();
outerPaint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
borderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);


Paint innerPaint = new Paint();
innerPaint.setARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
innerPaint.setAlpha(0);
innerPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

canvas.drawRect(0.0F, 0.0F, width, height, outerPaint);
canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(childRect.left, childRect.top, childRect.right, childRect.bottom), 8F, 8F, innerPaint);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `setXfermode()` of **Paint** and pass `PorterDuff.Mode.ADD` and `PorterDuff.Mode.ADD` as parameter in order to obtain inner transparency region instead of adding alpha to paint.

Make the following changes in your code:

```
int width = canvas.getWidth();
int height = canvas.getHeight();
Rect childRect = this.getChildRect();

Paint outerPaint = new Paint();
outerPaint.setColor(Color.LTGRAY);
outerPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.ADD));
outerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

Paint innerPaint = new Paint();
innerPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
innerPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
innerPaint.setAntiAlias(true);

canvas.drawRect(0.0F, 0.0F, width, height, outerPaint);
canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(childRect.left, childRect.top, childRect.right, childRect.bottom), 8F, 8F, innerPaint);
```